# Convert Date format Url rewrite rule iis

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting

I have this Url

/news/2015/08/08/news-title

I want to write rewriterule to redirect to the same url but without 0 for month or day so the final url will be like this

/news/2015/8/8/news-title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
<rule name="DateRule" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="news/(\d*)/0(\d)/0(\d)/(.*)" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="news/{R:1}/{R:2}/{R:3}/{R:4}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

I've done it as a *Temporary Redirect (307)* because it makes testing easier. To do it as a *Permanent (301)* one change it to `redirectType="Permanent"`.

Comment: Thanks Actually 2015 and news-title is not static

Comment: No worries, give me a sec